# checkout a file from a different branch into a different path in your current branch

Tags: git, path, copy, git-branch, git-checkout

So I know we can checkout files from other branches into our current working branch with :

```
git checkout [someOtherBranch] [path/to/file]
```

What I'm hoping is that something like this is possible :

```
git checkout [someOtherBranch] [path/to/file] [path/we/want/to/copy/to]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can `cherrypick` the commits for that file, maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cat the contents of the file and then use standard shell redirection to put it wherever you want.

```
git show [someOtherBranch]:path/to/file > newpath/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for